# Laravel CSRF token for API (prod API access from localhost and prod site)

Tags: laravel, deployment, csrf, laravel-10, csrf-token

What's the best practise when it comes to developing FE &BE regarding Laravel Sanctum / CSRF?

I built my app with Laravels CSRF token auth, as on the site (10.x) says that's recommended for SPAs.Works fine on local / dev, with postman and react as a frontend too.

However, just now I've deployed to DigitalOcean and now can't access my API from Postman on my machine.

Makes sense, Cross-Site request...but haven't found a good solution.

**Setup is:**
domain.com/api -> confirmed to work after deployment
.env: I added the localhost:3000 (react) "domain" to my .env, with my prod site url too.

CSRF token stuff works 100% in localhost environment (with both FE and BE running locally).

I looked up answers and most old posts (5y+) recommended I go with API token instead of CSRF.
**Isn't that less secure?**

Another solution I found was to basically disable (protected $except = ['*'] and similar "solutions" - I see no point in these).

I'm pretty new and would like to use the most secure features (especially if they're built in), but now I'm pretty confused.

*Ideal usecase would be that I can use my prod API as a BE for my dev FE aswell.*

Obviously wouldn't be too happy rewriting stuff now, but better late than never.

Thank you all!

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your configs. It could be as simple as a missing `.` or something more substantial. I found this video helpful, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zKoS8GsKK8.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it :)